# Why long literal can be assigned to float variable while float datatype uses less memory?

Tags: java

float uses 32 bits and long uses 64 bits. Why is this allowed by the compiler then?

```
float x = 5555555555555555555L;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range of `float` is broader than the range of `long`. So while you can certainly lose precision with an assignment like this (and can when assigning a `long` value to `double` too), the general magnitude is already representable - so there's never be a need to throw an exception due to it being out of range, for example.

The JLS ([section 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) says this:

> A widening primitive conversion from `int` to `float`, or from `long` to `float`, or from `long` to `double`, may result in *loss of precision* - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).